# Randomly distributing integer values among columns

Tags: php, mysql, math, statistics

I'm making a card game and I need to previously create the cards and store them in a mysql table. I'm trying to figure out how to make a php script to create them.
Well, there are 6 categories of values that vary from 0 to 12 and every card has values for each  category. The sum of the values of the categories in each card MUST be 36. So each card is something like this:

- 6 - 9 - 2 - 10 - 6 - 3

OR

- 0 - 12 - 0 - 12 - 0 - 12

OR EVEN

- 6 - 6 - 6 - 6 - 6 - 6

I think if I could randomly generate like 50 or 60 cards it wold be awesome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 6-6-6-6-6-6? [Are you sure that's random?](http://search.dilbert.com/comic/Random%20Number%20Generator)

Comment: @MarkByers you mean like this? :P http://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: I know you already picked an answer, but check out my answer below...I think it has some merit over the other solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A really naive approach is:

```
/* return an array of 6 numbers between 0 and 12 that sum to 36 */
generate_card() {
    $numbers = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < 6; $i += 1) {
        $numbers[$i] = rand(0, 12);
    }
    if (array_sum($numbers) !== 36) {
        return generate_card(); // repeat until we find one that does sum to 36
    } else {
        return $numbers; // yay!
    }
}
```

I think this will perform well enough for a 'simple card game'.

Comment: tweak this to choose five cards at random and then choose the 6th card according to what will make 36.  If it's impossible with 1-12 value, then scrub everything and start over.  It's just as random as before, and saves a lot of unnecessary recursion.

Comment: Yea, there are many tweaks you could make to this algorithm. I think Sam posted a better one though. Which is essentially your idea only it will always complete it one loop.

Comment: @MarkByers it does, but as I explained in the comments on Sam's answer it isn't an issue in this case because the expected value lies neatly in the middle.

Comment: @MarkByers Well yes, though I mean "just as random" as "the sum must be 36," which is what really introduces the bias.

Comment: Actually, to generate a large amount of cards i had to go on trial and error until I got the cards generated, but being a process to be done just once, that's ok.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this should work - the logic may be a little off, I haven't tested it.

```
function generate_card() {
    $max_card = 12;  // What's the highest value of a card number?
    $min_card = 0;   // What's the lowest value of a card number?
    $num_cards = 6;  // How many numbers on a card?
    $total = 36;     // What's the desired sum?
    $numbers = array();
    $running_total = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $num_cards; ++$i) {
        $max = min($max_card, $total - $running_total); //The highest number we can choose
        $min = max($min_card, $total - $running_total - ($max_card * ($num_cards - ($i + 1)))); //The lowest number we can choose

        //- how much is left ? $total - $running total
        //- min is amount_left - ($max_card

        $number = rand($min, $max);
        $running_total += $number;
        $numbers[] = $number;
    }

    return $numbers;
}
```

Edit:  I misplaced a parenthesis and an index, it works correctly now.

Comment: Assuming that this algorithm works it's definitely an improvement over my 'naive' one. I would like to point out though that `++$i` is a very tricky construction. Why not just add 1 where you're actually using `$i`?

Comment: Oh, I did think of another thing. I suppose in this case it works because the expected value of each iteration is `6`, which is `36/6` but if you chose numbers from, for instance `0-14` you would get a strange kind of skew favoring lower numbers towards the end. It's not a problem in this case but something to keep in mind. Reshuffling the numbers might work in those cases.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen - what do you mean by 'tricky'?  It's just a standard `for` loop, although I suppose some people might use `$i++` instead.  Reshuffling is a good idea to ensure randomness.

Comment: Nope. It doesn't sum 36 in most of the cases.

Comment: @hbmuller - it just needed a little tweak to the order of operations, it's working correctly now.

Answer (score 0):

I know you've already picked an answer for this, but I thought I'd weigh in with my solution anyway, since I think it brings something to the table.

Part of the problem is that what's meant by a "random hand" is kind of nebulous here.  If you want a truly random hand of 6 cards that sum to 36, you have to have an equal chance of picking from all possible hands that sum to 36.

The number of ways a number can be summed is called *partitioning*.  I wrote an algorithm to generate all the possible partitions of 36.  That's seventeen-thousand-some partitions.  Then I weeded out any partition that used a number over 12, then I weeded out any partition that involved more than 6 numbers.  That left me with 676 possible hands of 6 cards summing to 36.

The approach I would take, to ensure complete randomness, is to randomly pick from an array of all possible hands.  It's more storage intensive (you have to store the array), but much quicker than any approach suggested (because you only pick one random number and then pluck it out of the array).  Here's the abbreviated code (full code to follow):

```
$allHands = array(
    array(12,12,12,0,0,0),
    array(12,12,11,1,0,0),
    array(12,12,10,2,0,0),
    array(12,12,10,1,1,0),
    // ...etc
);
$hand = $allHands[ rand( 0, count($allHands)-1 ) ];
shuffle( $hand );
// $hand is now a completely random hand of 6 cards summing to 36
```

Here's the complete array of all possible hands:

```
$allHands = array(
    array( 12, 12, 12, 0, 0, 0 ),
    array( 12, 12, 11, 1, 0, 0 ),
    array( 12, 12, 10, 2, 0, 0 ),
    array( 12, 12, 10, 1, 1, 0 ),
    array( 12, 12, 9, 3, 0, 0 ),
    array( 12, 12, 9, 2, 1, 0 ),
    array( 12, 12, 9, 1, 1, 1 ),
    array( 12, 12, 8, 4, 0, 0 ),
    array( 12, 12, 8, 3, 1, 0 ),
    array( 12, 12, 8, 2, 2, 0 ),
    array( 12, 12, 8, 2, 1, 1 ),
    array( 12, 12, 7, 5, 0, 0 ),
    array( 12, 12, 7, 4, 1, 0 ),
    array( 12, 12, 7, 3, 2, 0 ),
    array( 12, 12, 7, 3, 1, 1 ),
    array( 12, 12, 7, 2, 2, 1 ),
    array( 12, 12, 6, 6, 0, 0 ),
    array( 12, 12, 6, 5, 1, 0 ),
    array( 12, 12, 6, 4, 2, 0 ),
    array( 12, 12, 6, 4, 1, 1 ),
    array( 12, 12, 6, 3, 3, 0 ),
    array( 12, 12, 6, 3, 2, 1 ),
    array( 12, 12, 6, 2, 2, 2 ),
    array( 12, 12, 5, 5, 2, 0 ),
    array( 12, 12, 5, 5, 1, 1 ),
    array( 12, 12, 5, 4, 3, 0 ),
    array( 12, 12, 5, 4, 2, 1 ),
    array( 12, 12, 5, 3, 3, 1 ),
    array( 12, 12, 5, 3, 2, 2 ),
    array( 12, 12, 4, 4, 4, 0 ),
    array( 12, 12, 4, 4, 3, 1 ),
    array( 12, 12, 4, 4, 2, 2 ),
    array( 12, 12, 4, 3, 3, 2 ),
    array( 12, 12, 3, 3, 3, 3 ),
    array( 12, 11, 11, 2, 0, 0 ),
    array( 12, 11, 11, 1, 1, 0 ),
    array( 12, 11, 10, 3, 0, 0 ),
    array( 12, 11, 10, 2, 1, 0 ),
    array( 12, 11, 10, 1, 1, 1 ),
    array( 12, 11, 9, 4, 0, 0 ),
    array( 12, 11, 9, 3, 1, 0 ),
    array( 12, 11, 9, 2, 2, 0 ),
    array( 12, 11, 9, 2, 1, 1 ),
    array( 12, 11, 8, 5, 0, 0 ),
    array( 12, 11, 8, 4, 1, 0 ),
    array( 12, 11, 8, 3, 2, 0 ),
    array( 12, 11, 8, 3, 1, 1 ),
    array( 12, 11, 8, 2, 2, 1 ),
    array( 12, 11, 7, 6, 0, 0 ),
    array( 12, 11, 7, 5, 1, 0 ),
    array( 12, 11, 7, 4, 2, 0 ),
    array( 12, 11, 7, 4, 1, 1 ),
    array( 12, 11, 7, 3, 3, 0 ),
    array( 12, 11, 7, 3, 2, 1 ),
    array( 12, 11, 7, 2, 2, 2 ),
    array( 12, 11, 6, 6, 1, 0 ),
    array( 12, 11, 6, 5, 2, 0 ),
    array( 12, 11, 6, 5, 1, 1 ),
    array( 12, 11, 6, 4, 3, 0 ),
    array( 12, 11, 6, 4, 2, 1 ),
    array( 12, 11, 6, 3, 3, 1 ),
    array( 12, 11, 6, 3, 2, 2 ),
    array( 12, 11, 5, 5, 3, 0 ),
    array( 12, 11, 5, 5, 2, 1 ),
    array( 12, 11, 5, 4, 4, 0 ),
    array( 12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 1 ),
    array( 12, 11, 5, 4, 2, 2 ),
    array( 12, 11, 5, 3, 3, 2 ),
    array( 12, 11, 4, 4, 4, 1 ),
    array( 12, 11, 4, 4, 3, 2 ),
    array( 12, 11, 4, 3, 3, 3 ),
    array( 12, 10, 10, 4, 0, 0 ),
    array( 12, 10, 10, 3, 1, 0 ),
    array( 12, 10, 10, 2, 2, 0 ),
    array( 12, 10, 10, 2, 1, 1 ),
    array( 12, 10, 9, 5, 0, 0 ),
    array( 12, 10, 9, 4, 1, 0 ),
    array( 12, 10, 9, 3, 2, 0 ),
    array( 12, 10, 9, 3, 1, 1 ),
    array( 12, 10, 9, 2, 2, 1 ),
    array( 12, 10, 8, 6, 0, 0 ),
    array( 12, 10, 8, 5, 1, 0 ),
    array( 12, 10, 8, 4, 2, 0 ),
    array( 12, 10, 8, 4, 1, 1 ),
    array( 12, 10, 8, 3, 3, 0 ),
    array( 12, 10, 8, 3, 2, 1 ),
    array( 12, 10, 8, 2, 2, 2 ),
    array( 12, 10, 7, 7, 0, 0 ),
    array( 12, 10, 7, 6, 1, 0 ),
    array( 12, 10, 7, 5, 2, 0 ),
    array( 12, 10, 7, 5, 1, 1 ),
    array( 12, 10, 7, 4, 3, 0 ),
    array( 12, 10, 7, 4, 2, 1 ),
    array( 12, 10, 7, 3, 3, 1 ),
    array( 12, 10, 7, 3, 2, 2 ),
    array( 12, 10, 6, 6, 2, 0 ),
    array( 12, 10, 6, 6, 1, 1 ),
    array( 12, 10, 6, 5, 3, 0 ),
    array( 12, 10, 6, 5, 2, 1 ),
    array( 12, 10, 6, 4, 4, 0 ),
    array( 12, 10, 6, 4, 3, 1 ),
    array( 12, 10, 6, 4, 2, 2 ),
    array( 12, 10, 6, 3, 3, 2 ),
    array( 12, 10, 5, 5, 4, 0 ),
    array( 12, 10, 5, 5, 3, 1 ),
    array( 12, 10, 5, 5, 2, 2 ),
    array( 12, 10, 5, 4, 4, 1 ),
    array( 12, 10, 5, 4, 3, 2 ),
    array( 12, 10, 5, 3, 3, 3 ),
    array( 12, 10, 4, 4, 4, 2 ),
    array( 12, 10, 4, 4, 3, 3 ),
    array( 12, 9, 9, 6, 0, 0 ),
    array( 12, 9, 9, 5, 1, 0 ),
    array( 12, 9, 9, 4, 2, 0 ),
    array( 12, 9, 9, 4, 1, 1 ),
    array( 12, 9, 9, 3, 3, 0 ),
    array( 12, 9, 9, 3, 2, 1 ),
    array( 12, 9, 9, 2, 2, 2 ),
    array( 12, 9, 8, 7, 0, 0 ),
    array( 12, 9, 8, 6, 1, 0 ),
    array( 12, 9, 8, 5, 2, 0 ),
    array( 12, 9, 8, 5, 1, 1 ),
    array( 12, 9, 8, 4, 3, 0 ),
    array( 12, 9, 8, 4, 2, 1 ),
    array( 12, 9, 8, 3, 3, 1 ),
    array( 12, 9, 8, 3, 2, 2 ),
    array( 12, 9, 7, 7, 1, 0 ),
    array( 12, 9, 7, 6, 2, 0 ),
    array( 12, 9, 7, 6, 1, 1 ),
    array( 12, 9, 7, 5, 3, 0 ),
    array( 12, 9, 7, 5, 2, 1 ),
    array( 12, 9, 7, 4, 4, 0 ),
    array( 12, 9, 7, 4, 3, 1 ),
    array( 12, 9, 7, 4, 2, 2 ),
    array( 12, 9, 7, 3, 3, 2 ),
    array( 12, 9, 6, 6, 3, 0 ),
    array( 12, 9, 6, 6, 2, 1 ),
    array( 12, 9, 6, 5, 4, 0 ),
    array( 12, 9, 6, 5, 3, 1 ),
    array( 12, 9, 6, 5, 2, 2 ),
    array( 12, 9, 6, 4, 4, 1 ),
    array( 12, 9, 6, 4, 3, 2 ),
    array( 12, 9, 6, 3, 3, 3 ),
    array( 12, 9, 5, 5, 5, 0 ),
    array( 12, 9, 5, 5, 4, 1 ),
    array( 12, 9, 5, 5, 3, 2 ),
    array( 12, 9, 5, 4, 4, 2 ),
    array( 12, 9, 5, 4, 3, 3 ),
    array( 12, 9, 4, 4, 4, 3 ),
    array( 12, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0 ),
    array( 12, 8, 8, 7, 1, 0 ),
    array( 12, 8, 8, 6, 2, 0 ),
    array( 12, 8, 8, 6, 1, 1 ),
    array( 12, 8, 8, 5, 3, 0 ),
    array( 12, 8, 8, 5, 2, 1 ),
    array( 12, 8, 8, 4, 4, 0 ),
    array( 12, 8, 8, 4, 3, 1 ),
    array( 12, 8, 8, 4, 2, 2 ),
    array( 12, 8, 8, 3, 3, 2 ),
    array( 12, 8, 7, 7, 2, 0 ),
    array( 12, 8, 7, 7, 1, 1 ),
    array( 12, 8, 7, 6, 3, 0 ),
    array( 12, 8, 7, 6, 2, 1 ),
    array( 12, 8, 7, 5, 4, 0 ),
    array( 12, 8, 7, 5, 3, 1 ),
    array( 12, 8, 7, 5, 2, 2 ),
    array( 12, 8, 7, 4, 4, 1 ),
    array( 12, 8, 7, 4, 3, 2 ),
    array( 12, 8, 7, 3, 3, 3 ),
    array( 12, 8, 6, 6, 4, 0 ),
    array( 12, 8, 6, 6, 3, 1 ),
    array( 12, 8, 6, 6, 2, 2 ),
    array( 12, 8, 6, 5, 5, 0 ),
    array( 12, 8, 6, 5, 4, 1 ),
    array( 12, 8, 6, 5, 3, 2 ),
    array( 12, 8, 6, 4, 4, 2 ),
    array( 12, 8, 6, 4, 3, 3 ),
    array( 12, 8, 5, 5, 5, 1 ),
    array( 12, 8, 5, 5, 4, 2 ),
    array( 12, 8, 5, 5, 3, 3 ),
    array( 12, 8, 5, 4, 4, 3 ),
    array( 12, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4 ),
    array( 12, 7, 7, 7, 3, 0 ),
    array( 12, 7, 7, 7, 2, 1 ),
    array( 12, 7, 7, 6, 4, 0 ),
    array( 12, 7, 7, 6, 3, 1 ),
    array( 12, 7, 7, 6, 2, 2 ),
    array( 12, 7, 7, 5, 5, 0 ),
    array( 12, 7, 7, 5, 4, 1 ),
    array( 12, 7, 7, 5, 3, 2 ),
    array( 12, 7, 7, 4, 4, 2 ),
    array( 12, 7, 7, 4, 3, 3 ),
    array( 12, 7, 6, 6, 5, 0 ),
    array( 12, 7, 6, 6, 4, 1 ),
    array( 12, 7, 6, 6, 3, 2 ),
    array( 12, 7, 6, 5, 5, 1 ),
    array( 12, 7, 6, 5, 4, 2 ),
    array( 12, 7, 6, 5, 3, 3 ),
    array( 12, 7, 6, 4, 4, 3 ),
    array( 12, 7, 5, 5, 5, 2 ),
    array( 12, 7, 5, 5, 4, 3 ),
    array( 12, 7, 5, 4, 4, 4 ),
    array( 12, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0 ),
    array( 12, 6, 6, 6, 5, 1 ),
    array( 12, 6, 6, 6, 4, 2 ),
    array( 12, 6, 6, 6, 3, 3 ),
    array( 12, 6, 6, 5, 5, 2 ),
    array( 12, 6, 6, 5, 4, 3 ),
    array( 12, 6, 6, 4, 4, 4 ),
    array( 12, 6, 5, 5, 5, 3 ),
    array( 12, 6, 5, 5, 4, 4 ),
    array( 12, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4 ),
    array( 11, 11, 11, 3, 0, 0 ),
    array( 11, 11, 11, 2, 1, 0 ),
    array( 11, 11, 11, 1, 1, 1 ),
    array( 11, 11, 10, 4, 0, 0 ),
    array( 11, 11, 10, 3, 1, 0 ),
    array( 11, 11, 10, 2, 2, 0 ),
    array( 11, 11, 10, 2, 1, 1 ),
    array( 11, 11, 9, 5, 0, 0 ),
    array( 11, 11, 9, 4, 1, 0 ),
    array( 11, 11, 9, 3, 2, 0 ),
    array( 11, 11, 9, 3, 1, 1 ),
    array( 11, 11, 9, 2, 2, 1 ),
    array( 11, 11, 8, 6, 0, 0 ),
    array( 11, 11, 8, 5, 1, 0 ),
    array( 11, 11, 8, 4, 2, 0 ),
    array( 11, 11, 8, 4, 1, 1 ),
    array( 11, 11, 8, 3, 3, 0 ),
    array( 11, 11, 8, 3, 2, 1 ),
    array( 11, 11, 8, 2, 2, 2 ),
    array( 11, 11, 7, 7, 0, 0 ),
    array( 11, 11, 7, 6, 1, 0 ),
    array( 11, 11, 7, 5, 2, 0 ),
    array( 11, 11, 7, 5, 1, 1 ),
    array( 11, 11, 7, 4, 3, 0 ),
    array( 11, 11, 7, 4, 2, 1 ),
    array( 11, 11, 7, 3, 3, 1 ),
    array( 11, 11, 7, 3, 2, 2 ),
    array( 11, 11, 6, 6, 2, 0 ),
    array( 11, 11, 6, 6, 1, 1 ),
    array( 11, 11, 6, 5, 3, 0 ),
    array( 11, 11, 6, 5, 2, 1 ),
    array( 11, 11, 6, 4, 4, 0 ),
    array( 11, 11, 6, 4, 3, 1 ),
    array( 11, 11, 6, 4, 2, 2 ),
    array( 11, 11, 6, 3, 3, 2 ),
    array( 11, 11, 5, 5, 4, 0 ),
    array( 11, 11, 5, 5, 3, 1 ),
    array( 11, 11, 5, 5, 2, 2 ),
    array( 11, 11, 5, 4, 4, 1 ),
    array( 11, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2 ),
    array( 11, 11, 5, 3, 3, 3 ),
    array( 11, 11, 4, 4, 4, 2 ),
    array( 11, 11, 4, 4, 3, 3 ),
    array( 11, 10, 10, 5, 0, 0 ),
    array( 11, 10, 10, 4, 1, 0 ),
    array( 11, 10, 10, 3, 2, 0 ),
    array( 11, 10, 10, 3, 1, 1 ),
    array( 11, 10, 10, 2, 2, 1 ),
    array( 11, 10, 9, 6, 0, 0 ),
    array( 11, 10, 9, 5, 1, 0 ),
    array( 11, 10, 9, 4, 2, 0 ),
    array( 11, 10, 9, 4, 1, 1 ),
    array( 11, 10, 9, 3, 3, 0 ),
    array( 11, 10, 9, 3, 2, 1 ),
    array( 11, 10, 9, 2, 2, 2 ),
    array( 11, 10, 8, 7, 0, 0 ),
    array( 11, 10, 8, 6, 1, 0 ),
    array( 11, 10, 8, 5, 2, 0 ),
    array( 11, 10, 8, 5, 1, 1 ),
    array( 11, 10, 8, 4, 3, 0 ),
    array( 11, 10, 8, 4, 2, 1 ),
    array( 11, 10, 8, 3, 3, 1 ),
    array( 11, 10, 8, 3, 2, 2 ),
    array( 11, 10, 7, 7, 1, 0 ),
    array( 11, 10, 7, 6, 2, 0 ),
    array( 11, 10, 7, 6, 1, 1 ),
    array( 11, 10, 7, 5, 3, 0 ),
    array( 11, 10, 7, 5, 2, 1 ),
    array( 11, 10, 7, 4, 4, 0 ),
    array( 11, 10, 7, 4, 3, 1 ),
    array( 11, 10, 7, 4, 2, 2 ),
    array( 11, 10, 7, 3, 3, 2 ),
    array( 11, 10, 6, 6, 3, 0 ),
    array( 11, 10, 6, 6, 2, 1 ),
    array( 11, 10, 6, 5, 4, 0 ),
    array( 11, 10, 6, 5, 3, 1 ),
    array( 11, 10, 6, 5, 2, 2 ),
    array( 11, 10, 6, 4, 4, 1 ),
    array( 11, 10, 6, 4, 3, 2 ),
    array( 11, 10, 6, 3, 3, 3 ),
    array( 11, 10, 5, 5, 5, 0 ),
    array( 11, 10, 5, 5, 4, 1 ),
    array( 11, 10, 5, 5, 3, 2 ),
    array( 11, 10, 5, 4, 4, 2 ),
    array( 11, 10, 5, 4, 3, 3 ),
    array( 11, 10, 4, 4, 4, 3 ),
    array( 11, 9, 9, 7, 0, 0 ),
    array( 11, 9, 9, 6, 1, 0 ),
    array( 11, 9, 9, 5, 2, 0 ),
    array( 11, 9, 9, 5, 1, 1 ),
    array( 11, 9, 9, 4, 3, 0 ),
    array( 11, 9, 9, 4, 2, 1 ),
    array( 11, 9, 9, 3, 3, 1 ),
    array( 11, 9, 9, 3, 2, 2 ),
    array( 11, 9, 8, 8, 0, 0 ),
    array( 11, 9, 8, 7, 1, 0 ),
    array( 11, 9, 8, 6, 2, 0 ),
    array( 11, 9, 8, 6, 1, 1 ),
    array( 11, 9, 8, 5, 3, 0 ),
    array( 11, 9, 8, 5, 2, 1 ),
    array( 11, 9, 8, 4, 4, 0 ),
    array( 11, 9, 8, 4, 3, 1 ),
    array( 11, 9, 8, 4, 2, 2 ),
    array( 11, 9, 8, 3, 3, 2 ),
    array( 11, 9, 7, 7, 2, 0 ),
    array( 11, 9, 7, 7, 1, 1 ),
    array( 11, 9, 7, 6, 3, 0 ),
    array( 11, 9, 7, 6, 2, 1 ),
    array( 11, 9, 7, 5, 4, 0 ),
    array( 11, 9, 7, 5, 3, 1 ),
    array( 11, 9, 7, 5, 2, 2 ),
    array( 11, 9, 7, 4, 4, 1 ),
    array( 11, 9, 7, 4, 3, 2 ),
    array( 11, 9, 7, 3, 3, 3 ),
    array( 11, 9, 6, 6, 4, 0 ),
    array( 11, 9, 6, 6, 3, 1 ),
    array( 11, 9, 6, 6, 2, 2 ),
    array( 11, 9, 6, 5, 5, 0 ),
    array( 11, 9, 6, 5, 4, 1 ),
    array( 11, 9, 6, 5, 3, 2 ),
    array( 11, 9, 6, 4, 4, 2 ),
    array( 11, 9, 6, 4, 3, 3 ),
    array( 11, 9, 5, 5, 5, 1 ),
    array( 11, 9, 5, 5, 4, 2 ),
    array( 11, 9, 5, 5, 3, 3 ),
    array( 11, 9, 5, 4, 4, 3 ),
    array( 11, 9, 4, 4, 4, 4 ),
    array( 11, 8, 8, 8, 1, 0 ),
    array( 11, 8, 8, 7, 2, 0 ),
    array( 11, 8, 8, 7, 1, 1 ),
    array( 11, 8, 8, 6, 3, 0 ),
    array( 11, 8, 8, 6, 2, 1 ),
    array( 11, 8, 8, 5, 4, 0 ),
    array( 11, 8, 8, 5, 3, 1 ),
    array( 11, 8, 8, 5, 2, 2 ),
    array( 11, 8, 8, 4, 4, 1 ),
    array( 11, 8, 8, 4, 3, 2 ),
    array( 11, 8, 8, 3, 3, 3 ),
    array( 11, 8, 7, 7, 3, 0 ),
    array( 11, 8, 7, 7, 2, 1 ),
    array( 11, 8, 7, 6, 4, 0 ),
    array( 11, 8, 7, 6, 3, 1 ),
    array( 11, 8, 7, 6, 2, 2 ),
    array( 11, 8, 7, 5, 5, 0 ),
    array( 11, 8, 7, 5, 4, 1 ),
    array( 11, 8, 7, 5, 3, 2 ),
    array( 11, 8, 7, 4, 4, 2 ),
    array( 11, 8, 7, 4, 3, 3 ),
    array( 11, 8, 6, 6, 5, 0 ),
    array( 11, 8, 6, 6, 4, 1 ),
    array( 11, 8, 6, 6, 3, 2 ),
    array( 11, 8, 6, 5, 5, 1 ),
    array( 11, 8, 6, 5, 4, 2 ),
    array( 11, 8, 6, 5, 3, 3 ),
    array( 11, 8, 6, 4, 4, 3 ),
    array( 11, 8, 5, 5, 5, 2 ),
    array( 11, 8, 5, 5, 4, 3 ),
    array( 11, 8, 5, 4, 4, 4 ),
    array( 11, 7, 7, 7, 4, 0 ),
    array( 11, 7, 7, 7, 3, 1 ),
    array( 11, 7, 7, 7, 2, 2 ),
    array( 11, 7, 7, 6, 5, 0 ),
    array( 11, 7, 7, 6, 4, 1 ),
    array( 11, 7, 7, 6, 3, 2 ),
    array( 11, 7, 7, 5, 5, 1 ),
    array( 11, 7, 7, 5, 4, 2 ),
    array( 11, 7, 7, 5, 3, 3 ),
    array( 11, 7, 7, 4, 4, 3 ),
    array( 11, 7, 6, 6, 6, 0 ),
    array( 11, 7, 6, 6, 5, 1 ),
    array( 11, 7, 6, 6, 4, 2 ),
    array( 11, 7, 6, 6, 3, 3 ),
    array( 11, 7, 6, 5, 5, 2 ),
    array( 11, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3 ),
    array( 11, 7, 6, 4, 4, 4 ),
    array( 11, 7, 5, 5, 5, 3 ),
    array( 11, 7, 5, 5, 4, 4 ),
    array( 11, 6, 6, 6, 6, 1 ),
    array( 11, 6, 6, 6, 5, 2 ),
    array( 11, 6, 6, 6, 4, 3 ),
    array( 11, 6, 6, 5, 5, 3 ),
    array( 11, 6, 6, 5, 4, 4 ),
    array( 11, 6, 5, 5, 5, 4 ),
    array( 11, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 ),
    array( 10, 10, 10, 6, 0, 0 ),
    array( 10, 10, 10, 5, 1, 0 ),
    array( 10, 10, 10, 4, 2, 0 ),
    array( 10, 10, 10, 4, 1, 1 ),
    array( 10, 10, 10, 3, 3, 0 ),
    array( 10, 10, 10, 3, 2, 1 ),
    array( 10, 10, 10, 2, 2, 2 ),
    array( 10, 10, 9, 7, 0, 0 ),
    array( 10, 10, 9, 6, 1, 0 ),
    array( 10, 10, 9, 5, 2, 0 ),
    array( 10, 10, 9, 5, 1, 1 ),
    array( 10, 10, 9, 4, 3, 0 ),
    array( 10, 10, 9, 4, 2, 1 ),
    array( 10, 10, 9, 3, 3, 1 ),
    array( 10, 10, 9, 3, 2, 2 ),
    array( 10, 10, 8, 8, 0, 0 ),
    array( 10, 10, 8, 7, 1, 0 ),
    array( 10, 10, 8, 6, 2, 0 ),
    array( 10, 10, 8, 6, 1, 1 ),
    array( 10, 10, 8, 5, 3, 0 ),
    array( 10, 10, 8, 5, 2, 1 ),
    array( 10, 10, 8, 4, 4, 0 ),
    array( 10, 10, 8, 4, 3, 1 ),
    array( 10, 10, 8, 4, 2, 2 ),
    array( 10, 10, 8, 3, 3, 2 ),
    array( 10, 10, 7, 7, 2, 0 ),
    array( 10, 10, 7, 7, 1, 1 ),
    array( 10, 10, 7, 6, 3, 0 ),
    array( 10, 10, 7, 6, 2, 1 ),
    array( 10, 10, 7, 5, 4, 0 ),
    array( 10, 10, 7, 5, 3, 1 ),
    array( 10, 10, 7, 5, 2, 2 ),
    array( 10, 10, 7, 4, 4, 1 ),
    array( 10, 10, 7, 4, 3, 2 ),
    array( 10, 10, 7, 3, 3, 3 ),
    array( 10, 10, 6, 6, 4, 0 ),
    array( 10, 10, 6, 6, 3, 1 ),
    array( 10, 10, 6, 6, 2, 2 ),
    array( 10, 10, 6, 5, 5, 0 ),
    array( 10, 10, 6, 5, 4, 1 ),
    array( 10, 10, 6, 5, 3, 2 ),
    array( 10, 10, 6, 4, 4, 2 ),
    array( 10, 10, 6, 4, 3, 3 ),
    array( 10, 10, 5, 5, 5, 1 ),
    array( 10, 10, 5, 5, 4, 2 ),
    array( 10, 10, 5, 5, 3, 3 ),
    array( 10, 10, 5, 4, 4, 3 ),
    array( 10, 10, 4, 4, 4, 4 ),
    array( 10, 9, 9, 8, 0, 0 ),
    array( 10, 9, 9, 7, 1, 0 ),
    array( 10, 9, 9, 6, 2, 0 ),
    array( 10, 9, 9, 6, 1, 1 ),
    array( 10, 9, 9, 5, 3, 0 ),
    array( 10, 9, 9, 5, 2, 1 ),
    array( 10, 9, 9, 4, 4, 0 ),
    array( 10, 9, 9, 4, 3, 1 ),
    array( 10, 9, 9, 4, 2, 2 ),
    array( 10, 9, 9, 3, 3, 2 ),
    array( 10, 9, 8, 8, 1, 0 ),
    array( 10, 9, 8, 7, 2, 0 ),
    array( 10, 9, 8, 7, 1, 1 ),
    array( 10, 9, 8, 6, 3, 0 ),
    array( 10, 9, 8, 6, 2, 1 ),
    array( 10, 9, 8, 5, 4, 0 ),
    array( 10, 9, 8, 5, 3, 1 ),
    array( 10, 9, 8, 5, 2, 2 ),
    array( 10, 9, 8, 4, 4, 1 ),
    array( 10, 9, 8, 4, 3, 2 ),
    array( 10, 9, 8, 3, 3, 3 ),
    array( 10, 9, 7, 7, 3, 0 ),
    array( 10, 9, 7, 7, 2, 1 ),
    array( 10, 9, 7, 6, 4, 0 ),
    array( 10, 9, 7, 6, 3, 1 ),
    array( 10, 9, 7, 6, 2, 2 ),
    array( 10, 9, 7, 5, 5, 0 ),
    array( 10, 9, 7, 5, 4, 1 ),
    array( 10, 9, 7, 5, 3, 2 ),
    array( 10, 9, 7, 4, 4, 2 ),
    array( 10, 9, 7, 4, 3, 3 ),
    array( 10, 9, 6, 6, 5, 0 ),
    array( 10, 9, 6, 6, 4, 1 ),
    array( 10, 9, 6, 6, 3, 2 ),
    array( 10, 9, 6, 5, 5, 1 ),
    array( 10, 9, 6, 5, 4, 2 ),
    array( 10, 9, 6, 5, 3, 3 ),
    array( 10, 9, 6, 4, 4, 3 ),
    array( 10, 9, 5, 5, 5, 2 ),
    array( 10, 9, 5, 5, 4, 3 ),
    array( 10, 9, 5, 4, 4, 4 ),
    array( 10, 8, 8, 8, 2, 0 ),
    array( 10, 8, 8, 8, 1, 1 ),
    array( 10, 8, 8, 7, 3, 0 ),
    array( 10, 8, 8, 7, 2, 1 ),
    array( 10, 8, 8, 6, 4, 0 ),
    array( 10, 8, 8, 6, 3, 1 ),
    array( 10, 8, 8, 6, 2, 2 ),
    array( 10, 8, 8, 5, 5, 0 ),
    array( 10, 8, 8, 5, 4, 1 ),
    array( 10, 8, 8, 5, 3, 2 ),
    array( 10, 8, 8, 4, 4, 2 ),
    array( 10, 8, 8, 4, 3, 3 ),
    array( 10, 8, 7, 7, 4, 0 ),
    array( 10, 8, 7, 7, 3, 1 ),
    array( 10, 8, 7, 7, 2, 2 ),
    array( 10, 8, 7, 6, 5, 0 ),
    array( 10, 8, 7, 6, 4, 1 ),
    array( 10, 8, 7, 6, 3, 2 ),
    array( 10, 8, 7, 5, 5, 1 ),
    array( 10, 8, 7, 5, 4, 2 ),
    array( 10, 8, 7, 5, 3, 3 ),
    array( 10, 8, 7, 4, 4, 3 ),
    array( 10, 8, 6, 6, 6, 0 ),
    array( 10, 8, 6, 6, 5, 1 ),
    array( 10, 8, 6, 6, 4, 2 ),
    array( 10, 8, 6, 6, 3, 3 ),
    array( 10, 8, 6, 5, 5, 2 ),
    array( 10, 8, 6, 5, 4, 3 ),
    array( 10, 8, 6, 4, 4, 4 ),
    array( 10, 8, 5, 5, 5, 3 ),
    array( 10, 8, 5, 5, 4, 4 ),
    array( 10, 7, 7, 7, 5, 0 ),
    array( 10, 7, 7, 7, 4, 1 ),
    array( 10, 7, 7, 7, 3, 2 ),
    array( 10, 7, 7, 6, 6, 0 ),
    array( 10, 7, 7, 6, 5, 1 ),
    array( 10, 7, 7, 6, 4, 2 ),
    array( 10, 7, 7, 6, 3, 3 ),
    array( 10, 7, 7, 5, 5, 2 ),
    array( 10, 7, 7, 5, 4, 3 ),
    array( 10, 7, 7, 4, 4, 4 ),
    array( 10, 7, 6, 6, 6, 1 ),
    array( 10, 7, 6, 6, 5, 2 ),
    array( 10, 7, 6, 6, 4, 3 ),
    array( 10, 7, 6, 5, 5, 3 ),
    array( 10, 7, 6, 5, 4, 4 ),
    array( 10, 7, 5, 5, 5, 4 ),
    array( 10, 6, 6, 6, 6, 2 ),
    array( 10, 6, 6, 6, 5, 3 ),
    array( 10, 6, 6, 6, 4, 4 ),
    array( 10, 6, 6, 5, 5, 4 ),
    array( 10, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5 ),
    array( 9, 9, 9, 9, 0, 0 ),
    array( 9, 9, 9, 8, 1, 0 ),
    array( 9, 9, 9, 7, 2, 0 ),
    array( 9, 9, 9, 7, 1, 1 ),
    array( 9, 9, 9, 6, 3, 0 ),
    array( 9, 9, 9, 6, 2, 1 ),
    array( 9, 9, 9, 5, 4, 0 ),
    array( 9, 9, 9, 5, 3, 1 ),
    array( 9, 9, 9, 5, 2, 2 ),
    array( 9, 9, 9, 4, 4, 1 ),
    array( 9, 9, 9, 4, 3, 2 ),
    array( 9, 9, 9, 3, 3, 3 ),
    array( 9, 9, 8, 8, 2, 0 ),
    array( 9, 9, 8, 8, 1, 1 ),
    array( 9, 9, 8, 7, 3, 0 ),
    array( 9, 9, 8, 7, 2, 1 ),
    array( 9, 9, 8, 6, 4, 0 ),
    array( 9, 9, 8, 6, 3, 1 ),
    array( 9, 9, 8, 6, 2, 2 ),
    array( 9, 9, 8, 5, 5, 0 ),
    array( 9, 9, 8, 5, 4, 1 ),
    array( 9, 9, 8, 5, 3, 2 ),
    array( 9, 9, 8, 4, 4, 2 ),
    array( 9, 9, 8, 4, 3, 3 ),
    array( 9, 9, 7, 7, 4, 0 ),
    array( 9, 9, 7, 7, 3, 1 ),
    array( 9, 9, 7, 7, 2, 2 ),
    array( 9, 9, 7, 6, 5, 0 ),
    array( 9, 9, 7, 6, 4, 1 ),
    array( 9, 9, 7, 6, 3, 2 ),
    array( 9, 9, 7, 5, 5, 1 ),
    array( 9, 9, 7, 5, 4, 2 ),
    array( 9, 9, 7, 5, 3, 3 ),
    array( 9, 9, 7, 4, 4, 3 ),
    array( 9, 9, 6, 6, 6, 0 ),
    array( 9, 9, 6, 6, 5, 1 ),
    array( 9, 9, 6, 6, 4, 2 ),
    array( 9, 9, 6, 6, 3, 3 ),
    array( 9, 9, 6, 5, 5, 2 ),
    array( 9, 9, 6, 5, 4, 3 ),
    array( 9, 9, 6, 4, 4, 4 ),
    array( 9, 9, 5, 5, 5, 3 ),
    array( 9, 9, 5, 5, 4, 4 ),
    array( 9, 8, 8, 8, 3, 0 ),
    array( 9, 8, 8, 8, 2, 1 ),
    array( 9, 8, 8, 7, 4, 0 ),
    array( 9, 8, 8, 7, 3, 1 ),
    array( 9, 8, 8, 7, 2, 2 ),
    array( 9, 8, 8, 6, 5, 0 ),
    array( 9, 8, 8, 6, 4, 1 ),
    array( 9, 8, 8, 6, 3, 2 ),
    array( 9, 8, 8, 5, 5, 1 ),
    array( 9, 8, 8, 5, 4, 2 ),
    array( 9, 8, 8, 5, 3, 3 ),
    array( 9, 8, 8, 4, 4, 3 ),
    array( 9, 8, 7, 7, 5, 0 ),
    array( 9, 8, 7, 7, 4, 1 ),
    array( 9, 8, 7, 7, 3, 2 ),
    array( 9, 8, 7, 6, 6, 0 ),
    array( 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 1 ),
    array( 9, 8, 7, 6, 4, 2 ),
    array( 9, 8, 7, 6, 3, 3 ),
    array( 9, 8, 7, 5, 5, 2 ),
    array( 9, 8, 7, 5, 4, 3 ),
    array( 9, 8, 7, 4, 4, 4 ),
    array( 9, 8, 6, 6, 6, 1 ),
    array( 9, 8, 6, 6, 5, 2 ),
    array( 9, 8, 6, 6, 4, 3 ),
    array( 9, 8, 6, 5, 5, 3 ),
    array( 9, 8, 6, 5, 4, 4 ),
    array( 9, 8, 5, 5, 5, 4 ),
    array( 9, 7, 7, 7, 6, 0 ),
    array( 9, 7, 7, 7, 5, 1 ),
    array( 9, 7, 7, 7, 4, 2 ),
    array( 9, 7, 7, 7, 3, 3 ),
    array( 9, 7, 7, 6, 6, 1 ),
    array( 9, 7, 7, 6, 5, 2 ),
    array( 9, 7, 7, 6, 4, 3 ),
    array( 9, 7, 7, 5, 5, 3 ),
    array( 9, 7, 7, 5, 4, 4 ),
    array( 9, 7, 6, 6, 6, 2 ),
    array( 9, 7, 6, 6, 5, 3 ),
    array( 9, 7, 6, 6, 4, 4 ),
    array( 9, 7, 6, 5, 5, 4 ),
    array( 9, 7, 5, 5, 5, 5 ),
    array( 9, 6, 6, 6, 6, 3 ),
    array( 9, 6, 6, 6, 5, 4 ),
    array( 9, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5 ),
    array( 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 0 ),
    array( 8, 8, 8, 8, 3, 1 ),
    array( 8, 8, 8, 8, 2, 2 ),
    array( 8, 8, 8, 7, 5, 0 ),
    array( 8, 8, 8, 7, 4, 1 ),
    array( 8, 8, 8, 7, 3, 2 ),
    array( 8, 8, 8, 6, 6, 0 ),
    array( 8, 8, 8, 6, 5, 1 ),
    array( 8, 8, 8, 6, 4, 2 ),
    array( 8, 8, 8, 6, 3, 3 ),
    array( 8, 8, 8, 5, 5, 2 ),
    array( 8, 8, 8, 5, 4, 3 ),
    array( 8, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4 ),
    array( 8, 8, 7, 7, 6, 0 ),
    array( 8, 8, 7, 7, 5, 1 ),
    array( 8, 8, 7, 7, 4, 2 ),
    array( 8, 8, 7, 7, 3, 3 ),
    array( 8, 8, 7, 6, 6, 1 ),
    array( 8, 8, 7, 6, 5, 2 ),
    array( 8, 8, 7, 6, 4, 3 ),
    array( 8, 8, 7, 5, 5, 3 ),
    array( 8, 8, 7, 5, 4, 4 ),
    array( 8, 8, 6, 6, 6, 2 ),
    array( 8, 8, 6, 6, 5, 3 ),
    array( 8, 8, 6, 6, 4, 4 ),
    array( 8, 8, 6, 5, 5, 4 ),
    array( 8, 8, 5, 5, 5, 5 ),
    array( 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 0 ),
    array( 8, 7, 7, 7, 6, 1 ),
    array( 8, 7, 7, 7, 5, 2 ),
    array( 8, 7, 7, 7, 4, 3 ),
    array( 8, 7, 7, 6, 6, 2 ),
    array( 8, 7, 7, 6, 5, 3 ),
    array( 8, 7, 7, 6, 4, 4 ),
    array( 8, 7, 7, 5, 5, 4 ),
    array( 8, 7, 6, 6, 6, 3 ),
    array( 8, 7, 6, 6, 5, 4 ),
    array( 8, 7, 6, 5, 5, 5 ),
    array( 8, 6, 6, 6, 6, 4 ),
    array( 8, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5 ),
    array( 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 1 ),
    array( 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 2 ),
    array( 7, 7, 7, 7, 5, 3 ),
    array( 7, 7, 7, 7, 4, 4 ),
    array( 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 3 ),
    array( 7, 7, 7, 6, 5, 4 ),
    array( 7, 7, 7, 5, 5, 5 ),
    array( 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 4 ),
    array( 7, 7, 6, 6, 5, 5 ),
    array( 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5 ),
    array( 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 ),
);
```